# delete data from asp:GridView use modal-dialog

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, modal-dialog

I try to delete data that display in GridView after confirm it using twitter bootstrap. my gridview with modal-dialog as follow

```
<div class="panel  panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2 class="panel-title clearfix ">
            <div>
                <b>Name</b>
                <div style="float: left;">
                </div>

            </div>
        </h2>
    </div>




    <div class="panel-body">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="gridView" DataKeyNames="Id" runat="server"
                CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hove"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                OnRowEditing="gridView_RowEditing"
                OnRowCancelingEdit="gridView_RowCancelingEdit"
                OnRowUpdating="gridView_RowUpdating"
                OnRowDeleting="gridView_RowDeleting"
                OnRowCommand="gridView_RowCommand">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" ControlStyle-Width="0px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="txtid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Id") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Width="40px" Text='<%#Eval("Id") %>' />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Location_name") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Location_name") %>' />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="LocName" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" runat="server" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqBrName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="BrName" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="valid" ErrorMessage="?" ValidationGroup="validaiton" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>





                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Options">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm " runat="server" CommandName="Edit">                                                            
                                                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit</asp:LinkButton>

                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm " runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")%>' OnClientClick="return ConfirmDelete()">                                                            
                                                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Delete</asp:LinkButton>




                            <%-- Delete Form --%>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="DeleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delete" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="">Delete the data</h4>
                                        </div>



                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            Are You sure?
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblLName1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>' />
                                            <br />

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbde" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm " runat="server" CommandName="Delete">                                                            
                                                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Delete
                                            </asp:LinkButton>
                                        </div>





                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <%-- Delete Form --%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdate" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm " runat="server" CommandName="Update">                                                            
                                                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></span> Update
                            </asp:LinkButton>

                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm " runat="server" CommandName="Cancel">                                                            
                                                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Cancel
                            </asp:LinkButton>



                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>

                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
            </asp:GridView>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and my JavaScript function is

```
<script>

        function ConfirmDelete() {
            $('#DeleteModal').modal()
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

so when I try to delete the record by using the popup model it's not working, the model will work fine but the data in **lblLName1** allows will be the first record ID so when I confirm the first record will be deleted

could anyone helps me in that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone

after trying several ways I found the solution.
first, change the calling button from

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm " runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")%>' OnClientClick="return ConfirmDelete()">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

to

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")%>'
                                OnCommand="lbDelete_Command" CommandName='<%#Eval("Location_name")%>'>                                                            
                                                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> حذف</asp:LinkButton>
```

and in c# call function under **lbDelete_Command**

```
protected void lbDelete_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
        {

            HiddenField hf_id = row.FindControl("hf_Del_ID") as HiddenField;
            Label l_name = row.FindControl("lb_Del_Name") as Label;
            l_name.Text = e.CommandName.ToString();
            hf_id.Value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

        }

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "LaunchServerSide", "$(function() { ConfirmDelete(); });", true);
    }
```

and I edit the fields under **modal-body** division like follow

```
<div class="modal-body">
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf_Del_ID" runat="server" />
Are You sure?
<h4><asp:Label ID="lb_Del_Name" runat="server"/></h4>
</div>
```

I use the hidden field **hf_Del_ID** for delete purpose
and the label **lb_Del_Name** for display only

and also the deleting SQL in C# as follow

```
 try
    {
        HiddenField hf_id = (HiddenField)gridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("hf_Del_ID");

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from TABLE_NAME where Id=" + hf_id.Value, con);
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (result == 1)
        {
            loadData();

            lbl_msgDet.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lbl_msgDet.Text = " delete done";
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        lbl_msgDet.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lbl_msgDet.Text = (String)GetGlobalResourceObject("Err_msg", "MsgDeleteErr") + "<br/>" + ex.Message;
    }
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "LaunchServerSide", "$(function() { CallMsg(); });", true);
```

I hope the solution helps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this works for me... very easy

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="dgMyGrid"  ValidationGroup="grdMyGrid" OnDeleteCommand="dgRel_DeleteCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                 <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="FirstColumn">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="FirstColumnID" Text='<%# getFirstColumnName(Eval("FirstColumn").ToString())%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>


                <asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <div class="modal" id="myModal<%#Eval("MyIDToBound").ToString()%>">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title">Confirm</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p id="modal-help-text">Are you sure to remove item?</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                       <asp:Button   runat="server" ID="btnDelete" CssClass="btn btn-secondary" CommandName="Delete" Text="Yes"/>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary cancel"  data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<%#Eval("MyIDToBound").ToString()%>">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDeleteButton" Text="Delete"></asp:Label>
                            </button>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>
```